# Karma and afterlife

Tags: karma, swarga, mukti

In abrahmic relegion there's concept of heaven and hell. In buddhism or nastika relegion there is karma. But in Sanatana Dharma there is mention of both so I don't understand what will happen after death.
Like i have listened always that punya will take you to swarga and vice versa but also that good karma will affect next life. So what is truth?

1. Does our all effective karma gets carried on to next life till we gain mukti? Then how swarga and naraka comes into play?
2. Does our effective karma of this life decides our next life in swarga and naraka or differnet realms. Then would we get birth again in earth on basis of our new karmas in that realm? But then isn't our karmas only count in bhuloka for mukti? That's why even gods desire for human birth.
3. Same as 2nd but does our effective karmas divide in 2 parts? One to decide next life in earth and second to decide life in swarga?

Also how to gain mukti by doing karmas? Does too good karmas or net zero karma ensures mukti?

Comment: There are numerous questions on karma already asked on this forum which will answer your question. I suggest you do a forum search on karma.